# Chrome Extension: first created tab of window does not call chrome.tabs.onUpdated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a function that opens the first tab in a new window and then creates the rest of the tabs in that window. When creating the first tab, the title of the tab is not updated, but when creating the rest of the tabs, those titles are updated. The title of the first tab is stored in `tabIdsToTitles`, but for some reason `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo)` is not called.

## console

```
set FIRST tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]: zzz
set tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]: aadf
set tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]: jjj
send tabIdsToTitles[tabId] to content.js: aadf, id: 3361
send tabIdsToTitles[tabId] to content.js: jjj, id: 3364
```

## part of background.js

```
// stores title of tab for later use when tab is fully updated
var tabIdsToTitles = {};

/* creates the tabs in a new window */
function createWindowTabs(group, i, j)
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        // creates first tab in a new window
        chrome.windows.create({"url": group["tabUrls" + i][j], "state": "maximized"}, function(tab)
        {
            /* onUpdated not being called on first tab of window for some reason */
            var tabTitle = group["tabNames" + i][j];
            tabIdsToTitles[tab.id] = tabTitle;
            console.log("set FIRST tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]: " + tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]);
        })
    }
    else
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({"url": group["tabUrls" + i][j], "active": false}, function(tab)
        {
            var tabTitle = group["tabNames" + i][j];
            tabIdsToTitles[tab.id] = tabTitle;
            console.log("set tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]: " + tabIdsToTitles[tab.id]);
        })
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo)
{
    if (tabIdsToTitles[tabId] && changeInfo.status === "complete") 
    {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {getTitle: tabIdsToTitles[tabId]}, function(response){});
        console.log("send tabIdsToTitles[tabId] to content.js: " + tabIdsToTitles[tabId] + ", id: " + tabId);
    }
})
```

## content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.getTitle)
    {
        document.title = request.getTitle;
    }
})
```

Comment: See the documentation: chrome.windows.create returns a `window`, not `tab`.

Comment: Ah I see, I fixed it by accessing `window.tabs[0]` for the first tab in the window. Thanks!